# Is it possible to enable pit mode without using the button with SmartAudio?

Tags: betaflight, video-transmitters

I know that pit mode can't be enabled from Betaflight after power up with SmartAudio, but I think it is a bit annoying that you have to hold the button on the VTX during power up if you want to enable pit mode.

I am fine with pit mode being on every time I plug in the battery, since it can be disabled with a switch. My question is therefore if it is possible to have the VTX, specifically the TBS Unify pro v3, turn on with pit mode already enabled. I had the race variant before, and that one could do it. I just haven't found a way to do it on the v3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it w/scripting on FR Sky and other OpenTX system.  They are a good bunch of people: https://www.open-tx.org/